# Why is Clostridium difficile toxin A + B outdated in snomed?

Tags: data, toxins, healthcare-data, database, clostridium-difficile

I'm looking at the new version of the Snomed dictionary and the concept `707993000` **Clostridium difficile toxin A + B (substance)** is deactivated (and outdated) since version `20170731`. Can anybody explain me, why this happened?

We have used this concept for coding of results of laboratory examinations in our software system. Is there an alternative Snomed concept usable for the purpose of coding of evidence of the Clostridium difficile toxin A + B ?

Comment: It seems like the Biology SE community would be a better fit, as this really doesn't ask about C. diff's effect on human health.

Comment: Actually, this is more of a professional question for other medical professionals, but we have very few of them at this time on this site.  I haven't examined SNOMED for C diff but have found a pattern in other changes that they have frequently eliminated grouping-type categories (e.g. toxin A&B) and created individual categories.  (This is an observation, not a firm answer, so not worthy of  adding it as an answer below.  If I discover something more concrete I will write as an answer.)

Comment: And welcome @dedek!  We're in the process of redesigning our site to be more focused towards medical professionals.  Check out our meta in the meanwhile!

Comment: Thanks @DoctorWhom you are probably right, I found this note in `20170731` [release notes](https://confluence.ihtsdotools.org/display/RMT/SNOMED+CT+July+2017+International+Edition+-+SNOMED+International+Release+notes#SNOMEDCTJuly2017InternationalEdition-SNOMEDInternationalReleasenotes-2.2.15Substances) : **Concepts containing disjunctives were inactivated** . I also saw elsewhere that *disjunctive aggregates* in concepts are not acceptable...